# Udev rules: how to match only kernel devices (not partitions) after device #26?

Tags: arch-linux, udev

Some systems have more then 26 (block) devices (like hard disk drives), which the kernel names as follows:

```
/dev/sda
...
/dev/sdz
/dev/sdaa
/dev/sdab
/dev/sdac
...
```

Most udev rules examples are quite simple, only matching the first 26 devices, like for example:

```
ACTION=="add|change", KERNEL=="sd[a-z]|sr[0-9]", SUBSYSTEM=="block", ATTR{queue/rotational}=="0", ATTR{queue/scheduler}="deadline"
```

But how to match after the 26th device?
One can't write `sd*` because partitions like `sda1` should not be matched.

I can imagine writing another "or" (pipe symbol: `|`) to make the match, like:

```
KERNEL=="sd[a-z]|sd[a-z][a-z]|sr[0-9]"
```

Or split the match in a positive and negative part, like:

```
..., KERNEL=="sd[a-z]*|sr[0-9]", KERNEL!="sd[a-z]*[0-9]", ...
```

Is there a better way to write udev rules that are readable, do match device #27 and up, but not any partition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## `KERNEL=="sd*[!0-9]|sr*"`

Can be found at the operating system supplied udev rules themselves.

In this Arch Linux case, have a look at file:

```
/usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules
```

Section ATA:

```
$ grep /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules -e \"ATA\"
KERNEL=="sd*[!0-9]|sr*", ENV{ID_SERIAL}!="?*", SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi", ATTRS{vendor}=="ATA", IMPORT{program}="ata_id --export $devnode"
```